# Returning ComplexObject gives error: "A type by this name exists but is not a Breeze.Sharp.EntityType"

Tags: breeze-sharp

I have the following BreezeController:

```
[BreezeController]
public class FinanceiraController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<FinanceiraWS> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<FinanceiraWS>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    ..... other functions

    [HttpGet]
    public List<RegraInfo> RegrasAProcessar(string dataRef, string marcaID)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime data = DateTime.Parse(dataRef);

            IQueryable<RegraInfo> lista = _contextProvider.Context.GetRegrasAProcessar(data, marcaID);

            return lista.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

which exposes a function 'RegrasAProcessar' that is supposed to invoke 
a sqlserver function exposed in entityframework edmx file. As expected, the sqlserver function 'GetRegrasAProcessar'
returns a complexType that I want to send back to the client. 
The client in turn has this code declared:

```
public partial class RegraInfo  : BaseComplexObject
{
    public Nullable<System.Guid> Id { get {return GetValue<Nullable<System.Guid>>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public string Conta { get {return GetValue<string>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public string Natureza { get {return GetValue<string>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UltimoProcessamento { get {return GetValue<Nullable<System.DateTime>>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataProcessamento { get {return GetValue<Nullable<System.DateTime>>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ProximoProcessamento { get {return GetValue<Nullable<System.DateTime>>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public Nullable<decimal> Valor { get {return GetValue<Nullable<decimal>>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public Nullable<double> Qtd { get {return GetValue<Nullable<double>>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public string Token { get {return GetValue<string>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public string Parametro { get {return GetValue<string>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public string MarcaID { get {return GetValue<string>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataInicio { get {return GetValue<Nullable<System.DateTime>>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataFim { get {return GetValue<Nullable<System.DateTime>>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public string IdPeriodo { get {return GetValue<string>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public string Descricao { get {return GetValue<string>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public Nullable<bool> IsToken { get {return GetValue<Nullable<bool>>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
    public Nullable<int> Ordem { get {return GetValue<Nullable<int>>();} set { SetValue(value); } }
}
```

expecting to receive the class RegraInfo as a complexObject. The problem is that when I invoke the server function with this code:

```
try
{
    Dictionary<string, object> parametros = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parametros.Add("dataRef", dataRef.ToShortDateString());
    parametros.Add("marcaID", marcaID);
    var qry = new EntityQuery<RegraInfo>().From("RegrasAProcessar").WithParameters(parametros);
    var results = await manager.ExecuteQuery(qry);

    return results.ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ....
}
```

gives an error saying: "A type by this name exists but is not a Breeze.Sharp.EntityType".
What is wrong with this approach? Should I change something?
I would appreciate some help on this topic. Many thanks in advance.